# Add scalar property using Entity Framework 4.0 getting 3004 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have added scalar property in the table using Entity Framework 4.0 getting 3004 error which is relevant to mapping of table. How i can add mapping manually in the table?

I learn a lot and get to know many tricks as like delete and update model etc but i want to know add manually mapping.

I have already added properties related to new scalar entity in SSDL and MSL file but still getting error.

Any idea why?

Comment: You don't need to add properties to SSDL and MSL manually in this case. Where did you originally add the property? To EDMX designer? Do you have related column in the database? What approach are you using? Model first or Db first?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka add scaler property using edmx designer column already created in the database but when add scaler property it shows error in mapping but when remove the table and add the table again it remove the mapping from the other tables which are already added in the designer.

Comment: So if you have it in database why don't you simply update model from database? That is correct approach.

Comment: I did that but when i update model it remove all mapping from the other tables which are already mapped i don't why.